# Java configuration for int-amqp

Tags: java

I am trying to convert a XML based configuration to JAVA based configuration. Can someone please let me know the java annotation based configuration for the following

```
  <int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter 
    channel="ids-callForth" 
    queue-names="${app.callForthQueue}"
    connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory" 
    error-channel="rabbitErrorChannel" />
```

Comment: Questions about Java are off-topic here but could be on-topic on stackoverflow.